# Electrical Potential energy

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a confusion regarding potential energy. My book say that electrical  potential energy of charges does not depend upon the origin. I want to know that how this is not depend upon the origin.

Comment: Which origin would that be?

Comment: Can you provide the context and quote the exact wording?  It's not clear what your book was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

The electrical potential energy of charges **does not** depend upon the origin. It **depends** only upon the relative distances between the charges themsleves.

**Explanation:**

Wherever you place the group of charges (anywhere in space), the `Electric Potential Energy of the system of charges` will be the same (if the relative distances of the charges remain the same).

For an `electric potential` to exist all we need is `one charged particle`, but for the existence of `electric potential energy` we need `at least two charged particles`.

Where the `group of particles` is in space is `not important`. All that `is important` is how far apart `the charges` are from `eachother`.

**Here is an example:**

Lets consider a general case, which deals with the potential in the neighborhood of a number of charges as depicted in the picture below:

[image]

Let r1,r2,r3 be the distances of the charges to a field point A, and r12, r13, r23 represent the distance between the charges.  The electric potential at point A is:

[image]

Example:

If we bring a charge Q from infinity and place it at point A the work done would be:

[image]

**The total Electric Potential Energy of this system of charges** namely, the work needed to bring them to their current positions can be calculated as follows: first bring q1 (zero work since there is no charge around yet), then in the field of q1 bring q2, then in the fields of q1 and q2 bring q3.  Add all of the work needed to compute the total work.

The result would be:

[image]

more [here](http://www.utm.edu/staff/cerkal/potential.html).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [website.](https://www.britannica.com/science/electric-potential)

The diagram shows the forces acting on a positive charge q located between two plates, A and B, of an electric field E.

> The potential energy for a positive charge increases when it moves against an electric field and decreases when it moves with the electric field; the opposite is true for a negative charge. Unless the unit charge crosses a changing magnetic field, its potential at any given point does not depend on the path taken.

[image]

Comment: Is the potential energy if an electric charg

Comment: Didn't quite catch that. Yes, that is the potential energy of an electric charge.

Comment: Suppose the potential energy of a bunch of electric charge is 5 joule. It means that work done by me to put the charge from infinty  to where they are is 5 joule.

Comment: In this situation I assume infinty as my origin. Than the potential energy of the bunch of charge is 5 joule. Is if I choose the origin  point other than infinty than also my

Comment: If i choose my origin other than infinity. Is than also Potential energy of the bubch of electric charges is 5 joule. Please please clear.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, then yes.

Comment: Suppose I choose the point A as origin. With respect to infinty the potential of A is 2volt. You are saying that work done by me put the charges from A to where they is also 5 Joule. Which can not be possible.

Comment: Sorry, I must be misinterpreting your question then. Please expand your original question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: My question is this as following

Comment: We define the electric potential energy of system if charge as that this is the amount if work that I have to do from infinty to that location where charge are. In this situation I considered infinty as my origin

Comment: Is the potential energy of the system remain same if I choose my origin other than infinity